# Combine normal and fixed-font in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

Wouldn't it be great if you could write text both as normal and fixed-font in the same message. In that way a discussion could avoid sometimes being fragmented.

ie. let's say I have a question/issue I want to discuss in the chat, and I want to supply some code to give an example. I would like to be able to write something like the following:

> Is there any way to write this better?
>
> ```
> public string convert(int number)
> {
>    return "this is the number " + number;
> }
> ```

Yes, it's a very lame example, and the code font size could possibly be smaller (preferably the same as the standard `code` fonts in the chat). And maybe there shouldn't have to be a double enter as in the these questions (to make the text a little more compact).

Answer (score 1):

Why not do this as two separate messages? Chat isn't Q&A: it's expected that the conversation will flow, so there's no need to post large messages all in one go. In fact, chat is specifically designed to *avoid* large blocks of text.

[As Marc Gravel said](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1183/214),

> Chat is a *conversation*, not a blog, and not a lecture auditorium. If you are writing paragraph after paragraph before submitting it, then frankly you're not using it for chat.

Comment: I agree to some degree..  However, this is not a new request, it's an issue raised by several persons. And I don't think anyone of us are trying to create "a large block of text". If that's what we want to avoid why not set a limit to 6 lines or so?

Comment: It's not an unreasonable request, but I don't think there's a pressing need for it. But then, I rarely use chat on the coding sites myself.